# iphone UItableview from xml

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a table view that i want to populate with information from xml. In viewdidload I tell the parser to start parsing. I store the information in an NSMUtableArray.

However when I get to this function it gives me a SIGABRT

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    NSString *celltext = [profileItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //SGABRT here

    NSString *celltitle = [profileFieldNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = celltext;

    cell.textLabel.text = celltitle;

    return cell;
}
```

I get a SIGABRT error saying "index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'" at the line:

```
NSString *celltext = [profileItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //SGABRT here
```

It seems that it is trying to put the data in the table before the parsing is complete. How do I avoid this?

Thanks

EDIT:  Here is the code that does the parsing:

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
   didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
     qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentElement = [[elementName copy] autorelease];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"fullname"]) 
    {
        tfullname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"DOB"])
    {
        tDOB = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"accommodation"])
    {
        taccommodation = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"nationality"])
    {
        tnationality = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"subject"])
    {
        tstudying= [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"fullname"])
    {
        [tfullname appendString:string];
    }

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"DOB"])
    {
        [tDOB appendString:string];
    }

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"accommodation"])
    {
        [taccommodation appendString:string];
    }

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"nationality"])
    {
        [tnationality appendString:string];
    }

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"subject"])
    {
        [tstudying appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"fullname"]) 
    {     
        namelabelstring = tfullname;
        NSLog(@"second attemp your name is %@", namelabelstring);
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"DOB"]) 
    {
        [profileItems addObject:tDOB];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"accommodation"])
    {
        [profileItems addObject:taccommodation];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"nationality"])
    {
        [profileItems addObject:tnationality];    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"subject"])
    {
        [profileItems addObject:tstudying];
    }
}
```

//////Here is the code where the arrays are created////////////

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    profileFieldNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
    profileItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [profileFieldNames addObject:@"Date of Birth:"];
    [profileFieldNames addObject:@"Nationality:"];
    [profileFieldNames addObject:@"Accommodation:"];
    [profileFieldNames addObject:@"Studying:"];

    //[[self tableView] reloadData];

    [self loadmemberprofiledata];

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileViewHeader" owner:self options:nil];

    [self setHeaderView]; 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like enough info.  Try putting an NSLog above that which logs the count of profileItems as well as the indexPath.row.  That may shed some light on how many items are available and what index is being asked for.   Also, you say the array may not be populated - is it populating the xml async in the bg?  What code does that?

Comment: Would help to see how you are populating profileItems and profileFieldNames.  I suspect one of those at least is actually empty.

Comment: yes it is an asynchronous connection...what is a bg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right - the table was trying to fill itself from an array that had not yet been filled (it was of 0 size). The solution a dirty hack; initialize it with spaces then use replaceatindexwith and then reload the table.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate an `NSMutableArray` from your XML file, then you can hook your `UITableViews` **DataSource** to the `NSMutableArray`.

Look into [**`NSXMLParser Class Reference`**](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/&ei=fYJpTrepFOeusQLvg6C1Bg&usg=AFQjCNGGk08bBzIOmWe0Y8jGQIbwORl7tw&sig2=pTU1_ny2VWa2NnxF05a9NA).

Comment: Hey,

An NSMutableArray is populated if I don't make the table fill up with values eventually the array is filled.

Comment: Are you sure that your parsing is adding objects to your array? You should `NSLog` **profileItems** at the end of `didEndElement`

Comment: agreed.  BTW, where is the parse called? (which in turn causes the callbacks to get called)